# gdal_translate and openweathermap xyz url

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, opendap, openweathermap-api

I'm trying to fetch [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/) GeoTIFF layers using gdal_translate from the website

```
https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=API_KEY
```

I used this command:

```
gdal_translate https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=API_KEY geo.tif
```

but I got this answer:

```
ERROR 1: An error occurred while creating a virtual connection to the 
DAP server: Error while reading the URL: 
https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png.ver. 
The OPeNDAP server returned the following message:
Unauthorized: Contact the server administrator.`
```

How do I fetch it?

Comment: does the link work in your browser? the server doesn't seem to be seeing your API key.

Comment: You should probably keep your api key a secret

Comment: just to let you test my problem that's it @IanTurton

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: @IanTurton when i use qgis gui i can add the tile easly from "tile server XYZ" section on the left of the software

Comment: Where did you read the example for your gdal_translate request? I would rather try to write an xml file like http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms_bluemarble_s3_tms.xml and use that as a datasource. Please notice that your command would try to read data from the whole world at full resolution. I recommend to use some reasonable value for the -spat parameter and select a smaller region of interest.

Comment: I don't see a problem in your example, so I don't think this is the problem here. But in general, you should always add single quotes to URLs, so nothing get's interpreted by bash.